# How to start a new sibling branch to a branch waiting to be accepted into develop that has all that branch's commits

Tags: git, visual-studio

The first branch that is waiting to be reviewed and accepted and essentially the commits in it took it from a completely empty repo to a copy of another repo we use as a starting point, but it has had a lot of stuff renamed and some more unit tests have been written.

I now have to make the "thing" more than just the template but with names changed, however I can't just make a new branch off develop and start working due to develop being empty.

I managed to get another reviewer but if I hadn't I would have to wait until Tuesday, I want to avoid that situation ever being an option, does anyone know how to avoid being blocked like this on git?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have your `featureInReview` branch and want to create a new feature branch that is based on the changes of your `featureInReview` branch, then you can just create a new branch `anotherFeature` starting from `develop` and merge `featureInReview` into your new branch.

In the case where develop is empty you might as well create your `anotherFeature` branch directly from `featureInReview`.

Comment: "In the case where develop is empty you might as well create your `anotherFeature` branch directly from `featureInReview`."

A co-worker told me this can cause issues, what happens when the  `featureInReview` branch gets merged into develop and deleted?

Comment: Deleting a branch does not mean deleting the commits it contains. So any new branches created from `featureInReview` will stay the same when `featureInReview` is deleted.